# oldest xmin is far in the past - Postgresql 9.4.4

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication, postgresql-9.4

I have a postgresql 9.4.4 in a production environment. 
Since 3 weeks, I'm receiving a lot of messages in pg_log:

```
<:::2020-04-06 23:59:59 BRT::2020-04-06 23:59:55 BRT:72350>|LOG:  automatic vacuum of table "template0.pg_catalog.pg_range": index scans: 0
    pages: 0 removed, 1 remain
    tuples: 0 removed, 6 remain, 0 are dead but not yet removable
    buffer usage: 20 hits, 0 misses, 0 dirtied
    avg read rate: 0.000 MB/s, avg write rate: 0.000 MB/s
    system usage: CPU 0.00s/0.00u sec elapsed 0.00 sec
<:::2020-04-07 00:00:00 BRT::2020-04-06 23:59:59 BRT:72428>|WARNING:  oldest xmin is far in the past
<:::2020-04-07 00:00:00 BRT::2020-04-06 23:59:59 BRT:72428>|HINT:  Close open transactions soon to avoid wraparound problems.
```

The warnings occurs a lot of times in the day, and it's look like happening on vacuum in each table of template0.pg_catalog.

Searching in other stack overflow questions, I found many answers, but none of them fit my case.

They say it can be 3 things:

1. Idle in transaction running for a long time:

Running **select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'idle in transaction'**, I get just one connection in this state, and it was opened today.

2. Prepared transactions transactions that have not been closed

Running **select * from pg_prepared_xacts;**, I got 9 lines and finished everyone with ROLLBACK PREPARED 'gid';. So, I don't have any prepared transactions right now.

3. Unused replication slot

Running **select * from pg_replication_slots**, I got just one line, and this replication is in use in another server.

```
slot_name;plugin;slot_type;datoid;database;active;xmin;catalog_xmin;restart_lsn
replica;;physical;;;t;2845561097;;584C/CC6604F0
```

So, I can't drop this one cause its in use. My two servers are running normally, except for these messages in the log.

```
My server:
autovacuum = on 
archive_mode = on
wal_keep_segments = 20
max_wal_senders = 3
max_replication_slots = 3
wal_level = hot_standby
hot_standby = on
archive_command = 'test -f %p && cp %p /opt/postgres/archxlog/%f'
```

My recovery.conf (on the other server, with standby replication):

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user= host= port= sslmode=disable sslcompression=1'
primary_slot_name = 'replica'
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Searching on google, i found this website:
http://micronetinternational.com/index.pl/en/00/https/postgrespro.com/list/thread-id/1556972

They say the problem is related to a substransaction that is pending on streaming.

Looking at the folder **pg_subtrans** folder, I founded a lot of so old files.

```
ls -lha | more
total 1,4G
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres  92K Abr 27 10:56 .
drwx------. 19 postgres postgres 4,0K Fev 21 16:38 ..
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres 256K Dez 11 11:07 A99B
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres 256K Dez 11 11:07 A99C
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres 256K Dez 11 11:07 A99D
-rw-------   1 postgres postgres 256K Dez 11 11:07 A99E
```

My replication is about of February of this year. So, these files are not recent. How is the best way to clear this folder?

Comment: Probably unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.4 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible. And you should at least use the latest 9.4 which is 9.4.25 and has [over 600 bugfixes](https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.4.4&to=9.4.25)

Comment: Please post output of `select * from pg_prepared_xacts;`: if you have rows in this view, it means that you still have prepared transactions waiting to be completed because row should be removed if transaction has been completed (ROLLBACK PREPARED does not mean that ROLLBACK has been done).

Comment: Do you get the same when you run `VACUUM (FREEZE, VERBOSE)` on the table manually?

Comment: Hello @a_horse_with_no_name ! Yeah, we already planning an update to this server. But i think thats unreleated. 

Hello @pifor, I already did rollback prepared, so i don't have any lines in this view right now. Can the transactions exists in another place? 

@paurenz, since I can't connect in template0, I can't execute `VACUUM (FREEZE, VERBOSE)`. Can I do it with another way?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem;

I stopped the replication and dropped the replication slot.
When I did this, the **pg_subtrans** was cleanned up, and the warning disappeared.

But, I lost my replication and had to start from scratch.

Everything is working normally now.

Thanks guys!